# Argument of type "volatile char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Tags: c, constants, volatile

I have a function whose prototype is as follows:

```
void foo(const char * data);
```

Elsewhere in my code, I have a global variable declared as follows

```
volatile char var[100];
```

Whenever I try to do this:

```
foo(var);
```

The compiler throws up the following error message:

**Argument of type "volatile char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"**

Why is that the case? As I understand it, the variable in my function is not allowed to change the pointer or its contents. I understand that because my global variable is volatile, it could potentially change at any time, but seeing as it is perfectly legal to have a volatile const variable, I don't see why I am getting this compiler error.

Thanks

--Amr

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because implicit conversions can *add* qualifiers to the target of pointer types, but not remove them.  So if you want your function to be able to accept `volatile` and/or `const` qualified pointers, you must declare it with both:

```
void foo(const volatile char * data);
```

Answer (score 9):

Because accessing a volatile variable using pointer to non-volatile is wrong. Either the object is volatile and then it should be accessed as such everywhere or you can access it as non-volatile and then it should not be marked as such. Make up your mind.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to handle a `volatile` argument in your function you must declare it as such:

```
void foo(const volatile char * data);
```

This would do the trick. But be aware that this also brings you all the overhead of `volatile` to the implementation of `foo`, i.e `data[something]` will be reloaded from memory at any point that you access it.

(Generally `volatile` is not so much of a good idea, unless you are doing device drivers or so. Even for parallel processing with threads it usually doesn't guarantee what you expect at first sight.)