# Using a volatile string as the format string with printf()

Tags: c, constants, volatile

Suppose I have the following function signature:

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ... );
```

Now, I have a string defined as follows:

```
volatile char command_str[256];
```

Now, when I want to pass this string to my printf function, I will get the following warning:

```
Warning 32  [N] 2943 : passing 'volatile char [256]' to parameter of type 'const char *' discards qualifiers    C:\P\parameter\parameter.c
```

I do not want to change the `printf` signature, the easiest solution to make the warning go away would be

```
printf((const char*)command_str, .......);
```

I have a feeling that this is not the best solution. What would be the correct thing to do? I cannot make `command_str` non-volatile since it is accessed within an interrupt.

Comment: there's no way to get printf to actually treat a string as volatile, i suggest you copy the string to non volatile memory right before the print, and then print

Comment: This appears to have been asked previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457677/argument-of-type-volatile-char-is-incompatible-with-parameter-of-type-const

Comment: If the string is modified by an interrupt, it can't be passed safely to `printf()` because any change while `printf()` is using it could throw things dangerously out of whack.

Comment: Your question is wrong. The warning has nothing to do with constness. The problem is that you have an array of volatile char and pass it to a function that doesn't expect this. The result can disastrous. For example, reading a volatile char could give a different result each time.

Comment: If it is modified in an interrupt, can you be sure that its value is correct all the time, like for instance the ending 0 there? Should there not be any lock/synchronization logic? Modifying a string is not atomic.

Comment: A volatile array is problematic.  `volatile` here implies any _one_ `char` can change at any time.  In a simplified case where `strlen(command_str)` does not changes, but changes 1 `char` at a time from `"e%d"` to `"e%e"` to `"ede"` to `"%de"`, performing a "atomic" copy of `"e%d"` or `"%de"` results in a consistent `printf()` format.  But copying the transitionally `"e%e"` or `"ede"` is a problem. IOW, it is not sufficient to block changes on `command_str` and make a copy. A copy must be made at a sensible time that requires whatever is changing `command_str` to signal when it is OK to do so.

Comment: Thank you all, the string is copied to a different string now and this copying is guarded by disabling interrupts and re-enabling them afterwards. Furthermore, data is now also read into a ringbuffer with the pointers being incremented withing that timespan as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `const` in `printf()`'s signature declares a promise `printf()` makes -- it won't mess with the data pointed to by `format` (therefore, both `char*` and `const char*` variables may be passed in for `format`).

Now, your array is `volatile` (and I expect you know the implication of that).  The compiler warns you, that this volatility is discarded in `printf()`'s scope -- you won't get volatile semantics for accesses to `format` *within* `printf()`.

As a suggestion what to do, I'd say evaluate whether you *really* want changes to the data be apparent midst- `printf()`.  I can't see a reason for wanting that, so making a local copy sounds reasonable.

Comment: There are a whole host of ways to shut down interrupts long enough to make a copy

Comment: A volatile buffer can't guarantee `\0` termination, and `printf` relies on it.

Comment: @Agent_L yes it can, as long as you always write it from the end first

Comment: @SteveCox true, but I assumed he'd state that if this is the case. Anyway this is the command string, so even writing from the end can still cause too many `%s`.

Comment: A lot depends on the nature of the changes made by the interrupt.  If, for example, it changes from `"%d = %s\n"` to `"%f, %f, %f = %s (%d)\n"` while `printf()` is passed an `int` and a `char *`, if `printf()` has not processed everything before the change occurs, the result is going to be a disaster (wildly undefined behaviour).  If it was changed from `"%d = %s\n"` to `"%d: %s\n"`, then about the worst that is likely happen is you lose the punctuation and see two spaces in the output.  Any more dramatic change is really worrisome.

Comment: Who cares though? We sigprocmask around a copy and this is a non-issue, the interrupt doesn't happen.

Comment: @SteveCox This entire question with several discussions was needed to come to this conclusion.

Comment: @Agent_L its the first comment I made

Comment: Thank you all, the string is copied to a different string now and this copying is guarded by disabling interrupts and re-enabling them afterwards. Furthermore, data is now also read into a ringbuffer with the pointers being incremented withing that timespan as well. Before I forget: No sigprocmask on that platform :-)

Answer (score 4):

The function are are passing to (`printf()`) expects the string to be mutable (`const *` means that `printf()` will not modify the content, not to be confused!), and the string you are trying to pass will get modified (well, to be precise the pointer to the string) by an interrupt.

How can you be you be sure that an interrupt will not modify the contents of the string between you calling `printf()` and `printf()` actually printing...? What prevents the interrupt from happening *while* `printf()` is working?

You need to mask interrupts while calling `printf()` (using `ASM {"CLI"}` or something more applicable to your platform), or just copy the string you pass to `printf()`:

```
// point a
char s[256];
strncpy(s, command_str, 256);
// point b
printf("%s", s);
// point c
```

This will fix the problem for `printf()`, but now you have a new race condition point **a** and **b**. I think  you need to refactor your code. You have bigger issues.

One solution might be:

```
char s[256];
mask_interrupts();
strncpy(s, command_str, 256);
unmask_interrupts();
printf("%s", s");
```

Comment: `strdup` shouldn't be used, as it relies on `\0` which can't be guaranteed on a volatile buffer. He knows it's length, so copying all 256 bytes is the way to go. Interrupt masking (or some other way of ensuring the buffer is not accessed) is still needed while copying.

Comment: Thanks, I will copy the string now while having interrupts disabled.